# How to use foreach in variable? I am stuck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to echo a variable which contains javascript source. My codes are

```
    if(!empty($errors)){


      $errors = array(1, 2);

$error = '';
foreach($errors as $err){
$error .= '<li>'.$err.'</li>';
                }

$alert = '
<script>
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "<div align=\"left\"><b>Errors:</b><br>
                <ul>'.$error.'</ul></div>",
  title: "We got some error.",
  buttons: {

    danger: {
      label: "Okay!",
      className: "btn-danger",
    },    
  }
});
</script>
                 ';
    }
```

In my body I am echoing $alert variable and result I get is

```
<script>
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "<div align=\"left\"><b>Errors:</b><br>
                <ul><li>2</li></ul></div>",
  title: "We got some error.",
  buttons: {

    danger: {
      label: "Okay!",
      className: "btn-danger",
    },    
  }
});
</script>
```

but I am not getting popup. And if I remove $error and echo this

```
$alert = '
<script>
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "<div align=\"left\"><b>Errors:</b><br>
                <ul><li>hello 1</li><li>hello 2</li></ul></div>",
  title: "We got some error.",
  buttons: {

    danger: {
      label: "Okay!",
      className: "btn-danger",
    },    
  }
});
</script> ';
```

So I get popup error. I am using this to echo $alert

```
<body>
    <?php if(isset($alert)){echo $alert;}?>
```

So what is problem? How to solve it? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console log?

Comment: Is this a typo? `$error = '<li>'.$err.'</li>';;`. First, it has double semi colons.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL about:24
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: @KevinAbelita, I tried that too. I know about two semi colons, I edited it but still its not working

Comment: (1) define `$error` before your loop. (2) change `$error = '<li>'.$err.'</li>';;` to `$error .= '<li>'.$err.'</li>';` ie. concat the error message using `.=`. (3) your `$error` is inside single quotes -> `$alert = ' ... $error ...'` so it won't be populated. Change to `$alert = ' ... '.$error.' ...'` or double quotes `$alert = " ... $error ..."`

Answer (score 2):

You are only getting the last error because you aren't appending the errors together

```
$error = "";
foreach($errors as $err){
    $error .= '<li>'.$err.'</li>';
}
```

or a better suggestion would be

```
$error = "<li>" . implode("</li><li>", $errors) . "</li>";
```

Comment: Done, I found solution any ways. ;) thanx for helping me. As you said I used  $error = "";
foreach($errors as $err){
    $error .= '<li>'.$err.'</li>';
}

Comment: but now I am getting the Array in first li. like this Errors:
* Array * error 1 * error 2 and like this

Comment: @viral4ever which method are you using?

Comment: @viral4ever `foreach` or `implode` or are you using something else?

Comment: Now its working fine. I solved this. Thanx anyways friends. I appreciate your help. :D